# How to find any child class of a base class then grab a variable from it

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a list consisting of various prefabs.

Each of the prefabs in this list has a script attached with various child classes that hold an integer 'dicesides' (representing a 6/8/10 sided dice). They are derived from a common base class 'dice_BaseClass'.

I would like to create a method that looks through each prefab in this list, finds the child class in the prefab (this is the difficult bit), grabs the dicesides variable and uses a roll dice method.

Heres some simplified examples of my dodgy code

Dice Parent Class

```
public class dice_BaseClass : MonoBehaviour {

private int dicesides = 8;

    public int DiceSides {
        get 
        { 
            return dicesides;
        }
        set
        {
            dicesides = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Dice child class 'BLUE' - simply sets the dicesides

```
public class dice_ChildClass_Red : dice_BaseClass
{
    public void Start () {
        DiceSides = 12;
    }
}
```

Dice child class 'RED' - simply sets the dicesides

```
public class dice_ChildClass_Blue : dice_BaseClass
{
    public void Start () {
        DiceSides = 8;
    }
}
```

And then in someother class that contains a list of prefabs with those child scripts attached to them...

```
public void RollDice () {

    foreach (GameObject go in goList){

        var diceClass = teffect.GetComponent<dice_BaseClass>();
        print (diceClass.DiceSides);
}
```

This doesn't work however. It just gets the base class default dicesides int.

I have also tried looking into generics, thinking that maybe this has something to do with it. The below is all nonsense but perhaps it will be useful to see where my thought process has gone and failed.

```
public void GenericTest<T>() where T : dice_BaseClass {

    foreach (GameObject go in goList){

        var testClass1 = teffect.GetComponent(typeof(T));

        var testClass2 = effectClass.GetType();

        var testClass3 = teffect.GetComponent("effectClass2");

        //effectClass = teffect.GetComponent(GetType().Name);

        print ("Hi " + effectClass2 );

    }
}
```

Thanks very much for reading through and for any tips / solutions you have.

Answer (score 1):

You could mark *DiceSides* property as virtual and override it in `Child` classes like this:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual int sides { get { return 8; } }
}

public class Child : Base
{
    public override int sides { get { return 10; } }
}
```

Test:

```
var arr = new [] { new Child(), new Base(), };

foreach (var a in arr) {
    Console.WriteLine(a.sides);
}
```

Result:

```
10
8
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, it did work but not quite the result I'm looking for as it relies on having to overide it each time I code a new child class, any method would also need overiding and almost writing from scratch. I think what I need is something that actually grabs the child class in unity and calls methods on it. I hope that makes some sense

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're calling `Start`, so the `DiceSides` property never gets set in the child classes.  You should be setting the property in the constructor:

```
public class dice_ChildClass_Red : dice_BaseClass
{
    public dice_ChildClass_Red() {
        DiceSides = 12;
    }
}

public class dice_ChildClass_Blue : dice_BaseClass
{
    public dice_ChildClass_Blue() {
        DiceSides = 8;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think every details in `MonoBehaviour` as base class and specifity of Unity: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html

Comment: @FSou1 So `Start` is called by `GetComponent`?  Sorry, I've never worked with Unity.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but i hope topic starter make sure that `Start` called before `print`